# How to call - (void) function in ordinary void function in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

for example:

```
-(void) myExample {  
    ..do something   
}  

void myOther(){  
    how to call myExample function here  
}
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting and syntax of the code posted.  Please do not embed the question inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call myOther, pass self reference. you should define the C method like this:

```
void myOther(id callBack)
```

Now you have self reference in c function.

```
void myOther(id callBack){  
   [callBack myExample];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If both methods are in same Class than you can directly call First method from Second methods as follows:

```
-(void) myExample {  
    ..do something   
}  

void myOther(){  
   call to myExample function
   [self myExample];
}
```

read docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

```
void getInputSource() {  
    TISInputSourceRef source = TISCopyCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSource();  
    NSLog(@"languages: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyBundleID));  
    NSLog(@"localized name: %@", TISGetInputSourceProperty(source, kTISPropertyLocalizedName));
    [self awakeFromNib];  
}  

-(void) awakeFromNib {  
    self.statusBar = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength];  
    NSImage* icon = [NSImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];  
    self.statusBar.image = icon;  
}
```